# How to get (up)values associated to C closures outside the given function?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, lua

In the Lua 5.2 manual we can find [the following text](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.4):

> When a C function is created, it is possible to associate some values
>   with it, thus creating a C closure (see lua_pushcclosure); these
>   values are called upvalues and are accessible to the function whenever
>   it is called.
>
> Whenever a C function is called, its upvalues are located at specific
>   pseudo-indices. These pseudo-indices are produced by the macro
>   lua_upvalueindex. The first value associated with a function is at
>   position lua_upvalueindex(1), and so on. Any access to
>   lua_upvalueindex(n), where n is greater than the number of upvalues of
>   the current function (but not greater than 256), produces an
>   acceptable (but invalid) index.

So, I created a callback function associated with an object pointer created with "new".

```
lua_pushstring(L,"myCallbackFunc");
Foo* ideleg = new Foo()
lua_pushlightuserdata (L, (Foo*)ideleg);
lua_pushcclosure(L, LuaCall<Tr,C,Args...>::LuaCallback,1);
lua_settable(L,-3);
```

And all the mechanics works very nicely... but now it's time to clean up, and I'm unable to get the pointer back so I can delete it, when I unregister the callback function or when I quit my program.

I do find the table entry using the following snippet:

```
lua_pushnil(L);
while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0)
{
    if (lua_isstring(L, -2) && lua_tostring(L,-2) == "myCallBackFunc" ) 
    {
        // get the pointer back and delete it!
    }
}
```

(Can I do it using `lua_getfield(L, -1, "myCallBackFunc");` ?)

But I'm unable to get the upvalue associated to the cclosure outside the `LuaCall<Tr,C,Args...>::LuaCallback()` function (Indeed inside this close function I can simply use `lua_upvalueindex(1)` but in this case I'm outside the close function...)

Is there a way to get this value so I can delete the pointer when I do not need it anymore ?

---

Edit: I did found the [lua_getupvalue](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_getupvalue) function that should do what I need, but at the moment I don't know how to get the cclosure stack index. So it still doesn't works yet.

Comment: "I did found the lua_getupvalue function that should do what I need, but at the moment I don't know how to get the cclosure stack index. So it's still doesn't works yet." This is a completely different problem, and it's impossible to answer without some idea of how you got to the point where you decided that the closure was no longer in use and the memory could be freed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Lua. But I *strongly* advise against it.

If you have access to that callback, if it's on the Lua stack, then it is entirely possible that some bit of Lua code has access to it as well. Which means that even though you *think* it will be destroyed, it actually won't be until Lua finishes with it. Destroying your closure puts it into a non-functioning state. Yet, because Lua may still have access to it, it is possible for the closure to be called *after* you destroyed its upvalue.

Badness ensues.

It would be better to put the pointer into a full userdata and attach a metatable to it with a `__gc` metamethod to do cleanup. That way, you can be certain that it will be be cleaned up when it truly is no longer in use.

However, if you insist on doing it your way, you can always use [`lua_getupvalue`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_getupvalue).

Comment: Hum I didn't even thought to the userdata. You are right I should go this way... I will try to modify the code to make it works with a userdata instead of a lightuserdata.